# Privilege awards did not show up in achievements list

Tags: bug

Today was a big day for me on Unix & Linux:

- I got a "Yearling" badge on the main site
- I got a "Yearling" badge on the meta site
- I earned the "create gallery chat rooms" privilege
- I earned the "established user" privilege

However, when click on the Achievements icon/menu, the list only shows the badges, not the privileges I earned. This is different than other SE sites where I see the new privileges awarded along with the badges.

I think this is a bug on the Unix & Linux site.

Comment: I'm in the unfortunate position of being unable to scroll far enough in my menu to see this behavior. My initial thought is that privileges are simply an indication that your rep has hit a certain milestone, and aren't represented in the achievements menu. The achievements menu -- to my recollection -- has only included reputation changes and badge awards. The most recent reference I can find is [from 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210187/307535), though.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I have earned privileges on other SE sites in the past week and these have shown up on the menu, as I said in my OP.

Answer (score 4):

You're a veteran Stack Exchange user (not just because of your nickname) and that means [some of the privilege notifications are not shown anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151679/295232). Specifically, all privileges with a threshold of 1,000 and less, and 'Approve or reject tag wiki edits' at 5,000 (presumably because you'll notice them in the Suggested Edit review queue which you already have access to). So this is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: This is confusing (a) because I had no idea I was a "veteran" (never heard of it on SE, never heard it made any difference), and I was notified last week that I achieved a 500 point privilege on (Spanish Language)[https://spanish.stackexchange.com/]. I guess that site is still running on the public beta rules. Is there somewhere I can see explicitly my "veteran" status?